# Can my Javascript generated Year Dropdown control the JQuery UI Calender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am building a datapicker for an online dashboard. I have a Dropdown menu that I built using Javascript in which users can select a year from 2010 to the current year, I can't figure out a way to control the Jquery calendar by which year I select (It has to be controlled by this dropdown menu - I'm already aware of the year dropdown that is build in to the datepicker) in the dropdown. I have to have it working this way due to the fact that there is leap years which makes Feb have an extra day. Any Help/advice would be greatly appreciated as I am relativelty new to Javascript.

```
<div class="yeardropdown">
    <select id="selectElementId" style="margin-left: 75px;"></select>
</div>

<div class="datepick">
    <div id="datepicker" style="margin-left: 25px"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript & jQuery:

```
// Year dropdown

var min = 2010,
max = new Date().getFullYear(),

select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

for (var i = min; i <= max; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}

select.value = new Date().getFullYear();

// Calendar

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        todayBtn: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        maxDate: new Date,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        showOtherWeeks: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showWeek: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you really want? Do you want to set the default year of date picker to selected year or...

Comment: I would like the Datepicker to display the year that has been selected in the Dropdown :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
<div class="yeardropdown">
    <select onchange="setDefaultYear(this)" id="selectElementId" style="margin-left: 75px;"></select>
</div>
```

change your javascript

```
function setDefaultYear(yearEle)
{
   var yearSelected = $(yearEle).val();
   $( ".selector" ).datepicker({
       defaultDate: new Date(yearEle,00,01)
   });
}
```